# Adding a Message Alert to an Ext JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm trying to add a message alert to an ext object but I can't seem to get it. If a user is logged in then an object is pushed with the URL and they can access it. If they're not logged in, a pop-up is supposed to appear and tell them to login.

Is there an easy way to add a pop-up to an Ext pdf link?

**Code**

```
var treeObj = [];
function loggedIn() {
   if (typeof isLoggedIn != 'undefined') {
      return isLoggedIn;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
 }

 if (loggedIn()) {

    treeObj.push({
       text: 'Test File',
       leaf: true,
       href: '/secure/test.pdf',
       cls: 'tree-pdf',
     });

  } else{

     treeObj.push({
        text: 'Test File',
        leaf: true,
        cls: 'tree-pdf',
        listeners: {
           render: function(c){
              c.getEl().on('click', function(){
                 Ext.Msg.alert('Insufficient Rights', 'You have selected a secure resource.');
              }, c);
           }
        }
     });
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why render a tree that the user needs to click to display they aren't logged in? Why not just display that they aren't logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fs4)

**Code snippet:-**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var treeObj = [],
            isLoggedIn;// = true;

        function loggedIn() {
            if (typeof isLoggedIn != 'undefined') {
                return isLoggedIn;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (loggedIn()) {
            treeObj.push({
                text: 'Test File',
                leaf: true,
                href: '/secure/test.pdf',
                hrefTarget: '_blank',
                cls: 'tree-pdf',
            });

        } else {
            treeObj.push({
                text: 'Test File',
                leaf: true,
                cls: 'tree-pdf'
            });
        }

        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            renderTo: document.body,
            title: 'Simple Tree',
            width: 300,
            height: 250,
            root: {
                text: 'Root',
                expanded: true,
                children: treeObj
            },
            listeners: {
                beforeitemclick: function (view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                    if (!loggedIn()) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Insufficient Rights', 'You have selected a secure resource.');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```